# How to only import specific ListItems in SPGridView

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

I can print all list items in the list in the SPGridView:

```
          SPList list = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"];
          SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;
          gvListItems.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();
          gvListItems.DataBind();
```

But nothing shows when I want to show specific list items filtered by inputs and dropdowns:

```
 string SPGridViewQuery = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Pracownik' /><Value Type='Text'>{2}</Value></Eq></And></Where>";

        var querySzukajacaRekordowTegoSamegoPracownika = new SPQuery();
        if (sprawdzanieUserow())
        {
            querySzukajacaRekordowTegoSamegoPracownika.Query = String.Format(SPGridViewQuery, "Dzien", TextBox3.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            querySzukajacaRekordowTegoSamegoPracownika.Query = String.Format(SPGridViewQuery, "Dzien", TextBox3.Text, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName.ToLower());
        }
        SPListItemCollection listaRekordowTegoSamegoPracownika = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].GetItems(querySzukajacaRekordowTegoSamegoPracownika);

        gvListItems.DataSource = listaRekordowTegoSamegoPracownika.GetDataTable();

        gvListItems.DataBind();
```

I want only retreive the matching list items and show them in SPGridView. How can I do that?

Comment: Your code looks right, do you know which filter is causing no rows to show? Try to simplify the code down til you can narrow down exactly what is going on

Comment: First of all I will try look at CAML Query.